# Need a way to get symbolicated crash from organiser for a game ported to ios using robovm framework

Tags: libgdx, crashlytics, flurry, robovm

I'm quite new and inexperienced with robovm framework and to be honest struggling a lot. I've ported few games for ios. The current problem I'm facing is crashes. I am able to get crash reports from organiser but then those crashes show all memory address, not sure what those are. Can anybody guide me to unsymbolicate them. Also I tried flurry crashlytics but the test crash I tried yesterday is still not reported on flurry console. Firebase crashlytics, was lost in trying to implement it! Would be thankful if i get some kind of sample project or guidelines to figure this out.

Comment: Can you send us the details of your instrumentation to support@flurry.com? We will look into this further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that on iOS, there is a huge difference between crashes on native iOS code and Java code. Crashes on the Objective C side are typically caused by some native code you are calling. Java crashes on the contrary will cause your game to get stuck. Try it by causing a NullPointerException in a debugging session.

For the Objective C crashes, you need to retrieve the crashes within xcode as you already found out. Follow the iOS guides.

For Java crashes, you need your own way to handle this on iOS. You should use Java's `DefaultCrashHandler`.